# Subclassing all classes in a 'chain' of subclasses

Tags: c#, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I came up with this example to clarify my question

We start with a base class

```
/// <summary>
/// Just a silly example class
/// </summary>
class CFileStream
{
    protected readonly string FilePath;

    public CFileStream(string filePath)
    {
        FilePath = filePath;
    }

    public virtual void Write(string s)
    {
        var stream = GetStream(FilePath);
        //etc
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Take filePath as an argument to make subclassing easier
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual FileStream GetStream(string filePath)
    {
        return new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    }
}
```

Create a subclass for it

```
/// <summary>
/// Building on top of CFileStream, created an encrypted version
/// </summary>
class CFileStreamEncrypted : CFileStream
{
    private readonly string _key;

    public CFileStreamEncrypted(string filePath, string key):base(filePath)
    {
        _key = key;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// For added complexity, let's also wrap a possible excepton
    /// </summary>
    public override void Write(string s)
    {
        try
        {
            base.Write(s);
        }
        catch (ImaginaryCryptoException ex)
        {
            throw new ImaginaryCustomException("bladibla", ex);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wrap the base stream in an imaginary crypto class
    /// </summary>
    protected override FileStream GetStream(string filePath)
    {
        return new CImaginaryCryptoStream(base.GetStream(filePath), _key);
    }
}
```

Now we wish to create a second subclass, but one that works with the initial filewriter as well as the encrypted version.

The first one makes sense

```
/// <summary>
/// Building on top of CFileStream, created an auto-split version
/// </summary>
class CFileStreamSplit : CFileStream
{
    public CFileStreamSplit(string filePath) 
        : base(filePath)
    {
    }

    protected int Counter;

    /// <summary>
    /// Close stream and move to next file at the appropriate time(s)
    /// </summary>
    public override void Write(string s)
    {
        do
        {
            Stream stream;
            if (ImaginaryBooleanMustSplit)
                stream = GetStream(FilePath);
            //etc
        } while (ImaginaryBooleanDataLeftToWrite);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get base stream but with altered filePath
    /// </summary>
    protected override FileStream GetStream(string filePath)
    {
        return base.GetStream(GetNextpath(filePath));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ignore proper extension / file-exists etc.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual string GetNextpath(string filePath)
    {
        return filePath + ++Counter;
    }
}
```

The second one (below this) is completely duplicate code, except for the constructor which now also requires the encryption key.

```
/// <summary>
/// Build the same auto-split version but this time on top of the encrypted subclass
/// </summary>
class CFileStreamSplitEncrypted : CFileStreamEncrypted
{
    public CFileStreamSplitEncrypted(string filePath, string key)
        : base(filePath, key)
    {
    }

    /*
     * Note that there are no changes below this line
     */

    protected int Counter;

    /// <summary>
    /// Close stream and move to next file at the appropriate time(s)
    /// </summary>
    public override void Write(string s)
    {
        do
        {
            Stream stream;
            if (ImaginaryBooleanMustSplit)
                stream = GetStream(FilePath);
            //etc
        } while (ImaginaryBooleanDataLeftToWrite);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get base stream but with altered filePath
    /// </summary>
    protected override FileStream GetStream(string filePath)
    {
        return base.GetStream(GetNextpath(filePath));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ignore proper extension / file-exists etc.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual string GetNextpath(string filePath)
    {
        return filePath + ++Counter;
    }
}
```

There are of course a lot of ways to reduce the amount of duplicate code here, but I have yet to find 'the best' way, if there even is such a thing. So; what is the least time-consuming, cleanest, most flexible way to get a round this issue in your opinion/experience?

Comment: Please elaborate when voting to close

Answer (score 1):

For the different modifications a decent way to go may be composition over inheritance. Set up your classes to only be responsible for a single thing, taking in a base stream on constructions.

```
interface ICFileStream
{
    void Write(string s);
    FileStream GetStream(string filePath);
}

/// <summary>
/// Just a silly example class
/// </summary>
class CFileStream: ICFileStream
{
    protected readonly string FilePath;

    public CFileStream(string filePath)
    {
        FilePath = filePath;
    }

    public void Write(string s)
    {
        var stream = GetStream(FilePath);
        //etc
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Take filePath as an argument to make subclassing easier
    /// </summary>
    protected FileStream GetStream(string filePath)
    {
        return new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Building on top of CFileStream, created an encrypted version
/// </summary>
class CFileStreamEncrypted : ICFileStream
{
    private readonly string _key;
    private readonly ICFileStream _stream;

    public CFileStreamEncrypted(string key, ICFileStream stream)
    {
        _key = key;
        _stream = stream;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// For added complexity, let's also wrap a possible excepton
    /// </summary>
    public void Write(string s)
    {
        try
        {
            _stream.Write(s);
        }
        catch (ImaginaryCryptoException ex)
        {
            throw new ImaginaryCustomException("bladibla", ex);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wrap the base stream in an imaginary crypto class
    /// </summary>
    protected FileStream GetStream(string filePath)
    {
        return new CImaginaryCryptoStream(_stream.GetStream(filePath), _key);
    }
}

class CFileStreamSplit : ICFileStream
{
    private readonly ICFileStream _stream;

    public CFileStreamSplit(ICFileStream stream) 
    {
        _stream = stream;
    }

    protected int Counter;

    /// <summary>
    /// Close stream and move to next file at the appropriate time(s)
    /// </summary>
    public void Write(string s)
    {
        do
        {
            Stream stream;
            if (ImaginaryBooleanMustSplit)
                stream = GetStream(FilePath);
            //etc
        } while (ImaginaryBooleanDataLeftToWrite);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get base stream but with altered filePath
    /// </summary>
    protected FileStream GetStream(string filePath)
    {
        return _stream.GetStream(GetNextpath(filePath));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ignore proper extension / file-exists etc.
    /// </summary>
    protected string GetNextpath(string filePath)
    {
        return filePath + ++Counter;
    }
}
```

So when you want a splitting-crypto-filestream:

```
new  CFileStreamSplit(new CFileStreamEncrypted("crypto-awesome-key", new CFileStream("C:\\blah...")));
```

This is more flexible so when you want to add LoggingCFileStream for example you don't need to add a separate class for each combination.

Comment: Thanks, I had considered using an interface as a base because it's definitely cleaner but the 'problem' with composition instead of inheritance means changing a lot more when refactoring existing code but I guess that's a trade-off for minimizing duplicate code

Comment: Oh by the way, doing this would also mean making the protected method (GetStream) public and that's something I wanted to avoid... any ideas?